# Print to text file does not brings any change to text file

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
file = ("/Users/Desktop/test_dict.txt")
token_dict = {}
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer = tokenize, stop_words='english', analyzer = 'word')
train_data_features = vectorizer.fit_transform(token_dict.values())
vocab = vectorizer.get_feature_names()
dist = sum(train_data_features)
with codecs.open(file, "wb","utf-8-sig") as output:
    for tag, count in zip(vocab, dist):
        print (count, tag)
        print('%10s ------ %10s' % (count, tag), file = output)
```

From the above code i am expecting is that it should write (count and tag) to the file. But after execution neither any error occurs nor anything is written to the file. I can't figure out where i am doing the mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [`python 3` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) for `print`: "*...print() cannot be used with binary mode file objects. For these, use file.write(...) instead.*"

Your are opening your file in binary mode (`"wb"`), either open it in text mode (`"w"`) or use `output.write(...)`.